# pushd within pushd -- possible?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a very simple batch script in which for every file copied to a staging directory, the script changes its working dir to that staging directory to do some work:

```
pushd C:\Shared\
for /r %%f in (*.dll) do (
    copy %%f C:\staging\.
    pushd C:\staging\.
      echo CWD is  %cd%
      REM do some work here
    popd
)
popd
```

However, to my surprise, only the first `pushd` gets done.

Is this a known limitation of DOS/Windows batch? If so, is there a quick workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works. Prove with the command `cd`:

```
pushd C:\Shared\
for /r %%f in (*.dll) do (
    pushd C:\staging\.
      echo CWD is  %cd%
      cd
    popd
)
popd
```

But because you use a variable (`%cd%`), that is changed and used within the same block, you need [delayed Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd C:\Shared\
for /r %%f in (*.dll) do (
    pushd C:\staging\.
      echo CWD is  %cd%
      echo correct CWD is !cd!
      cd
    popd
)
popd
```

Comment: Thank you! I would just add that in your 2nd code snippet a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is needed (I put it just before the 2nd `pushd` but that reaches maximum recursion level for setlocal, so I put it above all code).

Comment: yes, normally, `setlocal ...` is the second line of a batchfile (first one would be `@echo off`). Sorry, I am so used to this, that I forgot to mention. If you want the `setlocal ...` _inside_ the `for` loop, (it's normally not neccessary) you should `endlocal` before the loop ends (`)`).